# Why don't we have an isomorphism between $R[x]$ and $ R[[x]]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, power-series

$R$ is a ring. Why don't we have an isomorphism 
$$
R[x] \cong R[[x]]\ ?
$$

Comment: For instance, if $R$ is finite or countable, then $R[x]$ is countable, but $R[[x]]$ is uncountable. How could they be isomorphic?

Comment: what is R[[x]]?

Comment: I assume that $R[[x]]$ denotes the ring of formal power series over $R$..why would you expect these two things to be isomorphic?

Comment: Do you want $R$ to be fixed in any such isomorphism?

Comment: The two rings have different units.

Comment: When $R$ is a field, for example, the ideals of $R[[x]]$ are linearly ordered while the ideals of $R[x]$ are not. Another example of why one would not expect this isomorphism.

Answer (score 8):

The zero ring is the only commutative ring $R$ with $R[x] \cong R[[x]]$.

*Proof*: Assume $R[x] \cong R[[x]]$. It is known (Exercise 1.4 in Atiyah's book) that the Jacobson radical of $R[x]$ is equal to its nilradical. Thus, it would follow the same for $R[[x]]$. Since $x$ lies in the Jacobson radical of $R[[x]]$ (in fact, $1+xf$ is invertible for all $f \in R[[x]]$), it follows that $x$ is nilpotent, i.e. $x^n=0$ for some $n \geq 0$. This shows $R=0$.

The same proof shows: If $R,S$ are commutative rings with $R[x] \cong S[[x]]$, then $S=0$ and hence $R=0$.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't really see why Pierre's example is flawed. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @Wojowu $S[u_1,u_2,\ldots ][[v_1, v_2, \ldots]][x]$ is not isomorphic to $S[u_1,u_2,\ldots ][x][[v_1, v_2, \ldots]]$.  In the first case, elements have a finite degree in $x$; in the second, they might not (for instance, $xv_1+x^2v_1^2 + \ldots$).

Comment: That's perfectly correct, I see now.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon: This shows that the inclusion is no isomorphism.