# If $R[x]$ and $R[[x]]$ are isomorphic, then are they isomorphic to $R$ as well?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, formal-power-series

<s>There are examples of commutative rings $R \neq 0$ such that $R[x]$ is isomorphic to $R[[x]]$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1459413/110831); an example would be $R=S[x_1, x_2, \ldots][[y_1, y_2, \ldots]]$, with $S \neq 0$ any commutative ring).</s> This is false, see Martin Brandenburg's answer.

The following question was asked as a comment on the thread linked above: if $R$ is such that $R[x]\cong R[[x]]$, must we have that $R\cong R[x] \cong R[[x]]$?

<s>This is clearly true for the example above, which is (essentially) the only family of examples I could come up with.</s>

Comment: Sub-question: Does $R[x]\cong R[[x]]$ imply $R[x][y]\cong R[x][[y]]$?

Comment: We know that if $R$ has finite Krull dimension $n=dim (R)$, then $n<dim (R [x])$. So in this case the claim is not true. Also, for semi local ring $R$, since $R [x]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals, is not true.

Comment: Wait, $R[[y]][x]$ is only a subring of $R[x][[y]]$, right? For example, $1+xy+x^2 y^2 +\dotsc$ is contained in $R[x][[y]]$, but not in $R[[y]][x]$. (Therefore, I also don't understand the example mentioned in the other question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $R[x] \cong R[[x]]$ implies $R=0$ (see my answer to the previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1603419/110831)).

(I make this community wiki because this answer is rather trivial now.)

Comment: How is the example of $R=S[x_1, x_2, \ldots][[y_1, y_2, \ldots]]$ incorrect then?

Comment: See my comment above: We cannot exchange $[-]$ with $[[-]]$.